# Can't forbid numbers from a username that includes alphabetical characters

Tags: python, list, numbers

I am trying to write a code that forbids a new user from writing numbers in his user name.

I've mannegd to write this so far:

```
all_users = ['andrew', 'carolina', 'david']
new_user = "please provide a username"
if new_user.isnumeric():
       print(f"the username {new_user} is unavailable, please don't use numbers.")
elif new_user not in all_users:
       print(f"{new_user.title()}, welcome to the game!")
```

The problem is that the code works just fine until I try to mix alphabetic characters with numbers. I can't seem to find a way to tell Python to forbid usernames that contain both numbers and normal characters.

thanks in advance for any suggestions:)

Comment: `.isalpha()` returns true, if the string only contains letters (also unicode letters of all sorts of languages)

Answer (score 0):

`isnumeric()` returns true if the entire string is numeric.  You want to know if any character is numeric.

```
any(x.isnumeric() for x in new_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use regular expression https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/regex.html

Or simply test if any character is a numeric with

```
...

if any(char.isnumeric() for char in new_user):
    print(f"the username {new_user} is unavailable, please don't use numbers.")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to accept alphabetic characters, then check that a username has only alphabetic characters. Numbers are not the only non-alphabetic characters.

```
all_users = ['andrew', 'carolina', 'david']
new_user = "please provide a username"
if not new_user.isalpha():
   print(f"the username {new_user} is unavailable, please don't use non-alphabetic characters.")
elif new_user not in all_users:
   print(f"{new_user.title()}, welcome to the game!")
```